# How to add button tint programmatically

Tags: android, android-appcompat

In the new AppCompat library, we can tint the button this way:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/follow"
    android:id="@+id/button_follow"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/blue_100"
    />
```

How can I set the tint of the button programmatically in my code?
I'm basically trying to implement a conditional coloring of the button based on some user input.

Comment: Are you sure android:backgroundTint is working on Pre-Lollipop? I test with both Button and ApCompatButton but backgroundTint only seems to be working on Lollipop.

Comment: Please check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36006440/2826147).

Answer (score 259, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:backgroundTint) the related method to `android:backgroundTint` is [setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList list)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundTintList(android.content.res.ColorStateList))

**Update**

Follow this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html) to know how create a Color State List Resource.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:color="#your_color_here" />
</selector>
```

then load it using

```
setBackgroundTintList(contextInstance.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.your_xml_name));
```

where `contextInstance` is an instance of a `Context`

---

using AppCompart

```
btnTag.setSupportButtonTintList(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(Activity.this, R.color.colorPrimary));
```

Comment: which is not a color, but a ColorStateList. How to leverage that?

Comment: I get how to do it now thanks, but why would Android not allow you to just use a color manually? For every color of every button I have, I'll have to create an xml for a ColorStateList? That seems like a waste to me

Comment: I haven't checked the source code to be able to answer that.. but if you're interested i'm sure u can find how they're handling that and find out why they did it this way.. i'm sure there is a reason behind it.

Comment: setBackgroundTintList needs API 21 even if you call it on AppCompatButton.

Comment: Is it possible to use this on pre-Lollipop somehow? If so, for which kind of views?

Comment: getColorStateList(color) is now deprecated. You should add a theme as a second parameter, like: getColorStateList(color, theme). To add the currently used theme you can use `context.getTheme()`. Full code:
`setBackgroundTintList(contextInstance.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.your_xml_name, yourContext.getTheme()));`

Comment: or use ContextCompat like this : ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getContext(), R.color.your_xml_name)

Comment: The AppCompat support library offers a static helper: `ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList(View, ColorStateList)` that can be used all the way back to API 4. But it only works for views that implement `TintableBackgroundView`, for example `AppCompatButton` (instead of the usual `Button`).

Comment: Now, using `ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList(View, ColorStateList)`, as @Jon Adams suggested, makes even more sense since View.setSupportButtonTintList is restricted with `RestrictTo` annotation. Details here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/RestrictTo.html

Answer (score 124):

You could use

```
button.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(resources.getColor(R.id.blue_100)));
```

But I would recommend you to use a support library drawable tinting which just got released yesterday:

```
Drawable drawable = ...;

// Wrap the drawable so that future tinting calls work
// on pre-v21 devices. Always use the returned drawable.
drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);

// We can now set a tint
DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, Color.RED);
// ...or a tint list
DrawableCompat.setTintList(drawable, myColorStateList);
// ...and a different tint mode
DrawableCompat.setTintMode(drawable, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OVER);
```

You can find more [in this blog post](https://chris.banes.me/2015/04/22/support-libraries-v22-1-0/) (see section "Drawable tinting")

Comment: could u provide complete code to set tint using ur method?

Comment: the question is about a button, this answer is about a drawable. Why is this even displaying as an answer. Very misleading and unhelpful.

Answer (score 87):

Seems like views have own mechanics for tint management, so better will be put tint list:

```
ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList(
    editText, 
    ColorStateList.valueOf(errorColor));
```

Comment: Much better using it this way, so you get backwards compatibility from API 4!

Answer (score 40):

here's how to do it in kotlin:

```
view.background.setTint(ContextCompat.getColor(context, textColor))
```

Comment: Care, if you do this, you will set tint of the drawable. So, any view with the same background will be tint !!

Comment: this is for over API23

Answer (score 29):

In properly extending dimsuz's answer by providing a real code situation, see the following code snippet:

```
    Drawable buttonDrawable = button.getBackground();
    buttonDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(buttonDrawable);
    //the color is a direct color int and not a color resource
    DrawableCompat.setTint(buttonDrawable, Color.RED);
    button.setBackground(buttonDrawable);
```

This solution is for the scenario where a drawable is used as the button's background. It works on pre-Lollipop devices as well.

Answer (score 29):

---

### The simple way to do it

in Java

```
myButton.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(resources.getColor(R.id.white)));
```

in Kotlin

```
myButton.backgroundTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white) )
```

Comment: resources.getColor() is depricated.

Comment: It's better to use ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white)

Comment: Why not just use `ContextCompat.getColorStateList`? You can replace two function calls with just one

Answer (score 12):

Have you tried something like this?

```
button.setBackgroundTintList(getResources().getColorStateList(R.id.blue_100));
```

note that getResources() will only work in an activity. But it can be called on every context too.

Comment: You could create an xml as described here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList.html

Comment: getColorStateList appears to be deprecated.

Comment: setBackgroundTintList seem to require API level 21

Comment: button.
                        setBackgroundTintList(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(context,
                                R.color.blue)); worked for me

Answer (score 9):

You can use something like that:

```
myButton.backgroundTintList = AppCompatResources.getColorStateList(context, R.color.primary_variant)
```

Answer (score 8):

this is easily handled in the new Material Button from material design library, first, add the dependency:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha07'
```

then in your XML, use this for your button:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/accept"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/i_accept"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/grayBackground_500" />
```

and when you want to change the color, here's the code in Kotlin, It's not deprecated and it can be used prior to Android 21:

```
accept.backgroundTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(ResourcesCompat.getColor(resources, 
R.color.colorPrimary, theme))
```

Comment: Is there a similar one for the text tint itself?

Comment: you mean text as a button and you want to change the color of the background ?

Answer (score 7):

You can use DrawableCompat e.g.

```
public static Drawable setTint(Drawable drawable, int color) {
    final Drawable newDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
    DrawableCompat.setTint(newDrawable, color);
    return newDrawable;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The way I managed to get mine to work was by using `CompoundButtonCompat.setButtonTintList(button, colour)`.

To my understanding this works regardless of android version.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem. I wished to colour a complex drawable background for a view based on a color (int) value.
I succeeded by using the code:

```
ColorStateList csl = new ColorStateList(new int[][]{{}}, new int[]{color});
textView.setBackgroundTintList(csl);
```

Where color is an int value representing the colour required.
This represents the simple xml ColorStateList:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:color="color here"/>
</selector>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Minimum required API level 21

Comment: well you could just use `ColorStateList.valueOf(ColorInt)`

Answer (score 6):

If you are using `Kotlin` and `Material Design`, you can change color of your `MaterialButton` like this:

```
myButton.background.setTintList(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(context, R.color.myColor))
```

You can improve it even better by creating an extension function for your `MaterialButton` in order to make you code more readable and your coding little more convenient:

```
fun MaterialButton.changeColor(color: Int) {
    this.background.setTintList(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(context, color))
}
```

Then, you can use your function everywhere like this:

```
myButton.changeColor(R.color.myColor)
```

Answer (score 4):

For ImageButton you can use:

```
favoriteImageButton.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255)); // White Tint
```

Comment: setColorFilter is not defined for Buttons

Comment: It is, for ImageButton.

Comment: Oh ok, I didn't know about it. But OP is asking for Button. Can you edit your answer with this detail so I can remove my downvote?

Answer (score 4):

The suggested answer here doesn't work properly on android 5.0 if your XML based color state list references themed attributes..
For instance, I have an xml color state list like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="?colorPrimary" android:state_enabled="true"/>
    <item android:alpha="0.12" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface"/>
</selector>
```

Using this as my backgroundTint from xml works just fine on android 5.0 and everything else. However if I try to set this in code like this:

**(Don't do this)**

```
myButton.setSupportButtonTintList(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(myButton.getContext(), R.color.btn_tint_primary));
```

It actually doesn't matter if I pass the Activity or the button's context to ContextCompat.getColorStateList() method, neither will give me the proper color state list with respect to the theme the button is within. This is because using theme attributes in color state lists wasn't supported until api 23 and ContextCompat does not do anything special to resolve these. Instead you must use **AppCompatResources.getColorStateList()** which does its own resource parsing/theme attribute resolution on devices < API 23.

**Instead, you must use this:**

```
myButton.setSupportBackgroundTintList(AppCompatResources.getColorStateList(myButton.getContext(), R.color.btn_tint_primary));
```

TLDR: use **AppCompatResources** and not -ContextCompat- if you'll need resolved themed resources across all API versions of android.

For more information on the topic, [see this article](https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2016/08/contextcompat-getcolor-getdrawable.html).

Answer (score 4):

In addition to **Shayne3000**'s answer you can also use a color resource (not only an int color). **Kotlin** version:

```
var indicatorViewDrawable = itemHolder.indicatorView.background
indicatorViewDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(indicatorViewDrawable)
val color = ResourcesCompat.getColor(context.resources, R.color.AppGreenColor, null) // get your color from resources
DrawableCompat.setTint(indicatorViewDrawable, color)
itemHolder.indicatorView.background = indicatorViewDrawable
```

Answer (score 4):

There are three options for it using `setBackgroundTintList`

```
int myColor = Color.BLACK;
```

1. `button.setBackgroundTintList(new ColorStateList(EMPTY, new int[] { myColor }));`
2. `button.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(myColor));`
3. `button.setBackgroundTintList(contextInstance.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.my_color));`

Answer (score 3):

If you dont want to care about different versions of android, you can use this code, for basicaly any view. Worked for me.

```
val states = arrayOf(intArrayOf(android.R.attr.state_enabled))
                    val colors = intArrayOf(Color.GREEN) // your color here
                    val colorStateList = ColorStateList(states, colors)
                  ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList(yourButtonHere,colorStateList)
```

Kotlin version, wish a nice day to everyone reading this ;)

btw. if you created some drawable background shape this should override only only the tint color.

Answer (score 1):

```
checkbox.ButtonTintList = ColorStateList.ValueOf(Android.Color.White);
```

Use `ButtonTintList` instead of `BackgroundTintList`

Answer (score 1):

Tint can be added to button like:

```
filterBtn.setBackgroundTintList(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(context,R.color.colorPrimary))
```

Answer (score 0):

simple we can also use for an imageview

```
    imageView.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context,
R.color.COLOR_YOUR_COLOR));
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone wants to know how to set the **HTML color** code in the **background tint** *(in my case the color code is coming from backend)*

```
String htmlColorCode = "#FF0000";
int colorInt = Color.parseColor(htmlColorCode);
View myView = findViewById(R.id.my_view);
ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList(myView, ColorStateList.valueOf(colorInt));
```

Answer (score -1):

With Kotlin,

```
checkbox.buttonTintList = AppCompatResources.getColorStateList(context, color.colorPrimary)
```