# how to set `app:backgroundTint` for Textview programatically?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-appcompat, android-design-library

I am trying to add tint to my normal `Textview` not `AppCompatTextView`. I can add backgroundTint in xml using `app:backgroundTint` for it. Is there a way to do the same programatically for `Textview` itself.(I am targeting **kitkat** support)

Note: I have more `Textview`. so changing all of them will be over work

> `setSupportButtonTintList`only works for `AppCompat` controls. `setBackgroundTintList` shows no result in **kitkat**

Comment: I am not sure but can you try this?


Drawable drawable = getyourdrawablehere;
drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, Color.GREEN);
DrawableCompat.setTintMode(drawable, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OVER);
And after set the drawable for the editText:

textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(drawable, null, null, null);

Comment: @mihirraj the drawable is not setting. No error. but it does nothing

Answer (score 11):

This works for me

```
someTextView.getBackground().setTint(yourIntColor);
```

Answer (score 3):

**Note**

**`Added in version 23.1.1`** **So you can't use in 19**

**For AppCompat** , You can use **[setSupportButtonTintList](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/TintableCompoundButton.html#setSupportButtonTintList(android.content.res.ColorStateList))**

> void setSupportButtonTintList (ColorStateList tint)

```
tvOBJ.setSupportButtonTintList(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(CurrentActivity.this, R.color.your_color));
```

Comment: But it is not working for kitkat devices. I am glad you answering my question :)

Comment: got a helpful link read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29801031/how-to-add-button-tint-programatically

Comment: @jafarbtech  `added in version 23.1.1`

Comment: tint is not supported in API level below 21

Comment: `tvOBJ.setSupportButtonTintList` is only coming for `AppCompat` controls... not coming for ordinary `Textview` and `Button`

Comment: @jafarbtech what about `setBackgroundTintList` ?

Comment: @jafarbtech indeed . not supported

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya so is it a dead end?

Comment: @jafarbtech may be .

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList(](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewCompat#setbackgroundtintlist))

```
    val states = arrayOf(intArrayOf(android.R.attr.state_enabled))
    val colors = intArrayOf(Color.RED)
    val colorStateList = ColorStateList(states, colors)

    ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList(myView, colorStateList)
```