# How to Remove Background Color of Button to get Default Background in Android

Tags: android, button, background-color

I am Working on a Test Application in which every question is presented with Four options [those options are via Button]. When a User clicks a button and his answer is correct then background of that button Turns Green, and if his answer is incorrect it turns Red.
What i want to do is Reset the Button Background on Next Question.

After Searching a lot of People have asked the same Question and Accepted the answer as

```
  btnChoiceB.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
```

But the problem is, it turns the Whole Button Transparent, which is not my requirement. I Just want the default color Back.

Do Not Suggest

```
btnChoiceB.setBackgroundColor(null);
```

as it does not work.

This is What i want Back.
 [image: This is What i want Back.]

**UPDATE/ANSWERED**

As Suggested by quick learner,

```
btnChoiceB.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);
```

worked pretty cleanly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
btnChoiceB.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using android:backgroundTint . That, or try to look over this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29801150/5106700).

Answer (score 0):

The term you used was wrong it should be
      SetImageResources(R.drawable.image);
Your image can just be the color and the button text will hover it.

Answer (score 0):

themes.xml
Write this change default themes
style name Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar