# Programmatically change backgroundTint of ImageView with Vector Asset for background

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-xml

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorRed"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_delete"/>
```

As above I added an Android VectorAsset for ImageView background.

And I can change color of that Vector Asset from red to blue by xml like below.

```
android:backgroundTint="@color/colorBlue"
```

but I want to change its color programmatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using `ImageView` you can use `AppCompatImageView`, Because `setBackgroundTintList` is supported from API level 21, If you use `AppCompatImageView` you can change the tint color using `setSupportBackgroundTintList`.

so change you ImageView like this,

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorRed"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_delete"/>
```

So that you can call `setSupportBackgroundTintList` to set the tint color like this,

```
imageView.setSupportBackgroundTintList(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(this, R.color.colorBlue));
```

Comment: I am able to do it on `ImageView` but my app supports `v21` at least.

Answer (score 2):

programmatically you can achieve it like this:

```
img.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all background and src are different properties for a ImageView. 
Are you trying to set an Image to ImageView? First of all You have to use the property: 
`android:src="drawable"`

If you are using a vector asset you will need to use the property:`app:srcCompat="drawable"`

To understand the background, backgroundTint properties have a read at this: [What is the difference between background, backgroundTint, backgroundTintMode attributes in android layout xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32471009/what-is-the-difference-between-background-backgroundtint-backgroundtintmode-at)

AND to finally answer your question to background tint programmatically if that is what you really want, then here is a link [How to add button tint programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29801031/how-to-add-button-tint-programmatically)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29801031/how-to-add-button-tint-programmatically) question is related, but answers for buttons.

Original answer by [user A.A](https://stackoverflow.com/users/886001/a-a)

---

You should use [setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList list)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundTintList(android.content.res.ColorStateList))

Follow this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html) to know how create a Color State List Resource.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:color="#your_color_here" />
</selector>
```

then load it using

```
setBackgroundTintList(contextInstance.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.your_xml_name));
```

where `contextInstance` is an instance of a `Context`

using AppCompat

```
btnTag.setSupportButtonTintList(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(Activity.this, R.color.colorPrimary));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    imageView.apply {
        setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context, tintColor), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY)
        backgroundTintList = ContextCompat.getColorStateList(context, bgTintColor)
    }
```