# Changing button color causes the button to get bigger

Tags: android, button

[Here is what the button looks like after changing the color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwRmw.png)

[Here is what it looks like with "show layout bounds" on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6d18.png)

I have an "add note" button which shows a dialog for the user to enter a note.

I want to change the color of the button if a note is saved.

I've tried this:

```
btnNote.setBackgroundColor(view.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.NN));
```

and this:

```
btnNote.getBackground().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(view.getContext(), R.color.NN), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

But in both cases the button also becomes slightly bigger.

How can I change only the color of the button?

this is my button from my layout file:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnNote"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:text="Add note"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnDelete"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: give some padding in it then size will not resize during change of color

Comment: I added android:padding="2dp", but this did not change the result

Comment: change height once make it 50 dp

Comment: I tried it but the result is the same

Comment: then use once this btnNote.setBackgroundResource(Color.parse(colorName));

Comment: It also has the same result

Comment: hello @JiminyJillikers i have check             `btnAccept.setBackgroundTintList(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(this, R.color.yourcolor));` this code ti works perfectly from my side you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it dosen't become bigger,you can open the switch named "show layout bound" in developer option,the button's layout has not been changed,you can custom an drawable as the background.

Comment: I tried that, and you are right that the bounds do not become bigger (See the 2nd screenshot I added to the question). But the button does become bigger when the color is changed

Comment: I'll make a custom drawable for the background and check the result

Comment: Thanks, that is the solution

Answer (score 1):

I have tried all options and finally its working properly when, I Use `android:backgroundTint` attribute in your XML `Button` View.

Show below Snippet:-

```
android:backgroundTint="#6567dc"
```

**Problematically**

If in your `gradle` file `minSdkVersion` **is below 21** than you should **change it to 21** **OR** you can **wrap code in to if** condition that check device SDK support as below

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            btnAccept.setBackgroundTintList(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(this, R.color.yourcolor));
        }
```

using above code **output:**

[image]

**After color changed**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `background` , try **`backgroundTint`**

In xml,

```
android:backgroundTint="#yourcolor"
```

in java,

[**`setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList list)`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29801150/8867002)

For `AppCompatButton` ,

```
button.setSupportBackgroundTintList(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(this, R.color.yourcolor));
```

You can use ,

```
 ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList(AppCompatButton, ColorStateList)
```

Comment: I'd like to use that, but it says it requires API 21 and I am building for API 16.

Comment: Then you can use appcompat button and use the edited answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use background and don't use colour instead use drawable with different colours as you are using shape as background and setting colour to it does changes the colour but shape is not maintained so you need to add drawable shape with the colour you want to change