# Make image as marked when clicked on in a recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, imageview

I have a horizontal recyclerview with images and text, when i click on any item , i want it to be shown as marked. I don't want to select multiple items. Only one item at a time! Here is example i want to achieve 
[image]
Currently i am showing images in horizontal recyclerView

```
public class FilterPageHorizontalRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FilterPageHorizontalRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>
        {
            private int selectedPosition = -1;
    private static final String TAG = "RecyclerViewAdapter";

    //vars
    private ArrayList<String> mNames = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> mImageUrls = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context mContext;

    public FilterPageHorizontalRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> names, ArrayList<Integer> imageUrls) {
        mNames = names;
        mImageUrls = imageUrls;
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.horizontal_recycler_layout, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: called.");

        Glide.with(mContext)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(mImageUrls.get(position))
                .into(holder.image);

        holder.name.setText(mNames.get(position));

        holder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                selectedPosition = position;
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: clicked on an image: " + mNames.get(position));
                Toast.makeText(mContext, mNames.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_bed);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mImageUrls.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        CircleImageView image;
        TextView name;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        }

    }
}




public class HorizontalRecyclerView extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ArrayList<String> mNames = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> mImageUrls = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_horizontal_recycler_view);
        getImages();

        }

        private void getImages(){


            mImageUrls.add(R.drawable.home);
            mNames.add("Havasu Falls");

            mImageUrls.add(R.drawable.home);
            mNames.add("Trondheim");

            mImageUrls.add(R.drawable.home);
            mNames.add("Portugal");

            mImageUrls.add(R.drawable.home);
            mNames.add("Rocky Mountain National Park");


            mImageUrls.add(R.drawable.home);
            mNames.add("Mahahual");

            mImageUrls.add(R.drawable.home);
            mNames.add("Frozen Lake");


            mImageUrls.add(R.drawable.home);
            mNames.add("White Sands Desert");

            mImageUrls.add(R.drawable.home);
            mNames.add("Austrailia");

            mImageUrls.add(R.drawable.home);
            mNames.add("Washington");

            initRecyclerView();

        }

        private void initRecyclerView(){


            LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
            RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
            FilterPageHorizontalRecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new FilterPageHorizontalRecyclerViewAdapter(this, mNames, mImageUrls);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }`enter code here`
    }
```

[image: img] please see the example image in section Property types

Comment: https://imgur.com/ID4Uvlp this is what i want to achieve !

Comment: you need to modify your current layout from your ViewHolder, and setOnClickListener to the parent layout in your ViewHolder in onBIndViewHolder, after that make the required changes in the layout

Comment: can you please explain with some code?

Comment: I'll write an answer

Comment: https://imgur.com/ID4Uvlp have you checked this?

Comment: yes i saw that. I'll just give you basic idea though. Not complete code for that. You need to do other stuff own your own.

Comment: Ok Sir , That would be enough

Comment: Just let me know how can i select one item at a time and mark it as ticked and when i change the selection, previous one should be unticked automatically

Comment: I've written answer, make sure to accept it if it works.

Comment: yes sure ill accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Change your `R.layout.horizontal_recycler_layout` and make it like the one you want to achieve. Make sure the visibility of checkmark is `GONE`.
2. After doing that, change your `ViewHolder` to this.

> ```
> public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
>     View main;
>     CircleImageView image;
>     TextView name;
>
>     public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
>         super(itemView);
>         main = itemView;
>         image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
>         name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
>     }
>
> }
> ```

Now, you saved the base view in a variable so that you can set `OnClickListener` to complete layout inside `ViewHolder`

3. After doing that, inside your `onBindViewHolder`, set `onClickListener` to your main from `ViewHolder`. Here's how,

> ```
> holder.main.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener...
>         onClick(View view){
>              iconOfCheckMark.setVisibility(View.Visible);
>              holder.main.setBackgroundTintList(contextInstance.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.your_xml_name));
>         }
> );
> ```

That will change tint of your complete View(make it blue), and you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29801031/how-to-add-button-tint-programmatically) to how to give tint properly.

4. To make it so it only selects one item at a time, you can check out the sites below:

   [Single Selection in RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28972049/single-selection-in-recyclerview)

Comment: Will this ensure that only one item is selected at a time?