# how to make change a button background color in ontouchListener?

Tags: android, android-studio

i would like to change the background color in ontouchListener, i can change textColor but the background color remains unchanged: here is my code:

```
 Button usd=findViewById(R.id.button_divide);
    Button cdf=findViewById(R.id.button_multiply);
    usd.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {


        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPref.edit();
            editor.putString("currency","USD");
            editor.apply();
            usd.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#515de1"));
            usd.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            cdf.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            cdf.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#515de1"));
            return false;
        }

    });
```

Comment: have you tried setBackgroundTint() ? , Also I recommend you to use setOnClickListener instead, if touching is  not a use case ?

Comment: i tried setBackgroundTint() with ontouch and onclick listeners but i got the message from android studio: cannot resolve setbackgroundTint in button @oguzhanarslan

Comment: It is my bad sorry, you can find how to apply tint to a button programmatically here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29801031/how-to-add-button-tint-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

I's better to use the `selector` instead of code

```
<Button
     android:id="@+id/myButton"
     android:background="@drawable/selector_my_button"
     android:layout_width="100dp"
     android:layout_height="36dp"
     android:text="My Button" />
```

and the **selector_my_button.xml** is like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/white"/> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/blue"/> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:drawable="@color/black"/> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```